# Line spacing in PlantUML

Tags: plantuml

In PlantUml, I have an object like this:

```
object MyObject {
 #field1
 #field2
}
```

Which renders like this:

[image]

I want to have more space between the rows which have the field names (in this case, `field1`, `field2`).

I tried this:

```
skinparam object {
    DefaultPadding 40
    BoxPadding 40
    ParticipantPadding 40
    Padding 40
}

skinparam Default {
    DefaultPadding 40
    BoxPadding 40
    ParticipantPadding 40
    Padding 40
}
```

None of this skinning helped.

So is there a way to have spacing between the rows that contain field names?

Answer (score 0):

Not a real solution, but perhaps a possible workaround - you can use **newline characters** within the field names like this:

```
object MyObject {
 #field1\n
 #field2\n
}
```